# Button Layout Issues with JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

[image: Broken buttons]**Picture included** I have another issue where my buttons go to the top-right after the user inputs their name.  At this point, text shows up in the GUI on the LEFT side of the center which seems it would be "WEST" when I put "CENTER".  Code:

```
public TheDungeon()
{
  setTitle("InsertGameNameHere");
  setSize(750, 600);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  setLocationRelativeTo(null);

  buildButtonPanel();             

  characterInfoPanel = new JLabel("<html>Character information will go here</html>");
  gameScreen = new JLabel();
  inventoryPanel = new JLabel("<html>This is for the inventory</html>");

  add(gameScreen, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  setVisible(true);    

  //Program run
  userName();
  gameScreen.setText("<html>Welcome "+name+", to the game that has no name!</html>");
  classWindow();
} 

private void buildButtonPanel()
{
  // Create a panel for the buttons.
  buttonPanel = new JPanel();

  // Create the buttons.
  b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
  b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
  b3 = new JButton("Button 3");
  b4 = new JButton("Button 4");
  b5 = new JButton("Button 5");

  // Add the buttons to the button panel.
  buttonPanel.add(b1);
  buttonPanel.add(b2);
  buttonPanel.add(b3);
  buttonPanel.add(b4);
  buttonPanel.add(b5);
}


private void userName() {
name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What will your name be?");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why your program is behaving as it seems to be since when I ran it, it did not do this. You may wish to check your code to make sure that it's the code you're posting here. But regardless, I do have some suggestions:

- Best to not set the sizes of anything, but rather to let the components and the layout managers do this for you.
- Consider if you must overriding `getPreferredSize()` if you need to control the size of a component more fully.
- Call `pack()` on your top level window after adding all components and before calling `setVisible(true)`. This will tell the layout managers to do their things.
- Avoid extending JFrame since you will rarely need to override one of its innate behaviors.
- If you do add or remove components, or change their preferredSizes somehow after rendering your top-level window, you will want to call `revalidate()` and then `repaint()` on the component's container to have the container re-layout the components it holds and then redraw them.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TheDungeon2 extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 750;
   private static final int PREF_H = 600;
   private static final String[] BUTTON_LABELS = {"Button 1", "Button 2", 
         "Button 3", "Button 4", "Button 5"};
   private static final String WELCOME_TEXT = "Welcome %s to the game that has no name!";

   private JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
   private String name;   

   public TheDungeon2() {
      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0));
      for (String buttonLabel : BUTTON_LABELS) {
         JButton button = new JButton(buttonLabel);
         buttonPanel.add(button);
      }

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(welcomeLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   public void getAndSetName() {
      name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "What will your name be?");
      welcomeLabel.setText(String.format(WELCOME_TEXT, name));
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TheDungeon2 dungeon2 = new TheDungeon2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Nameless Game");

      dungeon2.getAndSetName();

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(dungeon2);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! How could I add an action listener to the buttons? I have the following code later in my program but the problem with the code you posted above, the buttons don't have specific names.  Could you show some code of how to do this?  

`warriorButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            userClass = "Warrior";
            classWindow.dispose();
            }});`

The linebreaks won't work, so I can't do a new line.. I tried <br/> and it doesn't seem to work. Sorry!

Comment: @Xearta: the example above was written with short cuts to just show the GUI formatting issues, including using a String array for creating the buttons. You will have to expand and alter your own solution. As for multiline display, consider using a JTextArea. You can change its appearance so that it matches that of a JLabel by calling its methods.

Answer (score 3):

I tested your code with an empty classWindow() method and the buttons are correctly placed in south,

for the CENTER issue, you should place something in WEST to have your text centred (even an empty panel) otherwise CENTER will take all the place,

look at this , i added this line :

```
add(new JButton("a button for test"),BorderLayout.WEST);
```

and here is the result :

[image: demo]

Comment: Another alternative is `JLabel.setText("TextToDisplay", JLabel.CENTER)`. No need to add a component to the `WEST/preferred name is LINE_START` now :-)